# Are meta questions now featuring in Hot Network Questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions

At this moment there are 4 meta-site questions on the HNQ list:

1. [Are History of Worldbuilding questions on topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/are-history-of-worldbuilding-questions-on-topic) (World Building Meta)
2. [2019 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380600/2019-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) (Meta StackOverflow)
3. [What if a translation in a post doesn't resolved in Google/Bing the way the poster says?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5995/what-if-a-translation-in-a-post-doesnt-resolved-in-google-bing-the-way-the-post) (Workplace Meta)
4. [Cool Project Ideas](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/cool-project-ideas) (Mathematica Meta)

When I first saw it, I only saw the SO Moderator question, so I assumed that this was a one-off special thing for the election; but now we've got four questions crept in. Was this an intentional change, or a bug?

Comment: I was just about to ask this.

Comment: Looks like it, yes: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7575310#7575310 (that chatroom takes only Hot Network Questions)

Comment: ... You mean 'yes' it's an intentional change, or 'yes' it's a bug? Admittedly my title was not so great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not an intentional change, no.

I'm paying down some tech debt in the HNQ-related code. Long story short, the code backing it is moving from the StackExchange.com project into the main Q&A project. Turns out, the way se.com filtered the site list took care of excluding private betas, child metas, etc.

The check's fixed now, so the list should exclude metas as it did before.

Comment: Why not make Meta Stack Exchange part of HNQ?

Comment: I seem to be the only one using the HNQ's RSS feed around here, but I'll say it again: the more questions, the better. I get many interesting meta questions about technical issues or policy changes. I wish we stopped removing sites and questions from the HNQ, or at least the RSS feed.

Comment: @Sonic because it's a meta site.

Comment: If the check is fixed, then why is https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949940/local-storage-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null on HNQ?

Comment: @forest because it's Russian interference!

Comment: @forest That's not a meta site. We also had to change how we check for non-English questions. Long story short, we switched to a language detector library and checking the title alone, not the body. Might need to revisit that (or hard-exclude international sites entirely), evidently... but for the moment, this is what we've got.

Comment: @AdamLear [Japanese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324606/japanese-so-question-appears-in-hnq) is also appearing, even when majority of the title is non-English.

Comment: @AdamLear [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53422/mery%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%92%E3%81%84%E7%B7%9A%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%96%E3%81%97%E6%96%B9) still appears. Can we soon get a fix which maybe checks if the URL starts with a language part (`ja.stackoverflow` or `ru.stackoverflow`). There is really no need to have those questions displayed (they can still be HNQ) if one can't even understand anything. A customizable language filter for that would be perfect, though I guess that would take some time

Comment: @XtremeBaumer International SO sites are fully excluded from HNQ now.