# Do https://meta.stackexchange.com/ questions make it to the HMP or HNQ?

Tags: discussion, meta, hot-questions

I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280506/235923 and feel like I used to see Main Meta posts.

Did something get lost in the shuffle when HMP was removed/re-instated?

Comment: It seems that they used to be there before 2014: [Do we need MSE in the hot list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229777)

Comment: @Martin Interesting! It seems like it was guided by the `featured` back then as well so it's merely switched locations over the years.

Answer (score 9):

Meta Stack Exchange (this site) is considered a meta site, hence questions asked here will not show in the Hot Network Questions list. That's the case [since April 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229780/152859).

Since Meta Stack Exchange has no real "parent site", there's nowhere to show Hot Meta Posts like in other sites.

**However**, one very powerful feature that does exist, is that questions having the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag on Meta Stack Exchange will appear in the sidebar of **all sites in the network**. This is unique to this site, being the "main meta".

Comment: There was a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324487/are-meta-questions-now-featuring-in-hot-network-questions) at one point and metas were appearing in the HNQ.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus for like 20 minutes... not worth considering it.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly why I denoted it as a bug. Aside from that I think my confusion stems from the power of the `featured` tag. I knew I've seen Stack Meta questions in the HMP before but the infrequency is explained by the `featured` tag. I guess if I wanted to see Hot Stack Meta posts then I would just mosey on over to https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot

Comment: Hot Meta Posts is for per-site meta questions; Featured questions on MSE have their own category as far as I remember, no such question now to check though.

Comment: So in the context of the [current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xViMG.png) where would featured Main Meta Posts be presented?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus under "Featured on Meta", found [old screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/zjdDuED.png?2).

Comment: Per a comment on my post, MSE used to appear in the HNQ but it was only via the `featured` tag much like it is today. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229777/do-we-need-mse-in-the-hot-list